# Reducing Table Width of WP_List_Table

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I created a table using WP_List_Table class in a WordPress plugin. It basically outputs some information from the database. The Id column is taking too much space inside the table and I am trying to reduce the width. Is there a way to do this in PHP(while extending the class) or will I have to do so in CSS. If so how? I prefer a PHP solution.

[image]

Comment: The PHP solution is to be consistent with the rest of the WP UI: don't show the ID to begin with.

Comment: The Id is needed for inserting shortcodes into posts and pages to display the instance of the autoquote program there.

Comment: Sounds like *fantastic* user interface. ;-) Check the file where `WP_List_Table` is defined, I'm 99% there's a useful hook in there. Possibly in the table definitions or something. Whichever it is, you should be able to add an extra CSS class if necessary — though I'd wager a useful one exists already, so check that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a style within "admin_head" hook.

Try this:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'style_my_table' );

public function style_my_table() {
      echo '<style type="text/css">';
      echo '.wp-list-table .id { width: 5%; }';
      echo '.wp-list-table .name { width: 40%; }';
      echo '.wp-list-table .description  { width: 35%; }';
      echo '.wp-list-table .rating { width: 20%; }';
      echo '</style>';
}
```